# Tax in the Netherlands

Tags: income-tax, salary, netherlands

I have a question regarding tax in the Netherlands. I have a gross monthly salary of 3,500. I am allowed to enter the 30% tax ruling (young employee with masters). Then what is my monthly net income? I tried the site https://thetax.nl and got a monthly net salary of 3,042. However, on https://www.blueumbrella.nl/income-tax-return/income-tax-calculator/ I only get a monthly net salary of 2,723. Hence I am a bit confused :). Is there any official site to get reliable data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you entered a monthly salary in one, a yearly salary in the other, and forgot to account for vacation allowance (commonly 8% or 1/12, check your employer for details).